# What does keyboard shortcut alt-shift-f10 do in Fedora 27

Tags: linux, fedora, keyboard-shortcuts

A common shortcut I use in IntelliJ is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, but in Fedora 27 it doesn't do anything which makes me think the shortcut is intercepted before it gets to IntelliJ.

I was wondering if anyone knows what is using this shortcut?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, it seems as though the toggle maximization state shortcut is interfering (FYI, I am using CentOS, but this should be the same for Fedora).

To fix, go to settings/devices/keyboard and look for the "Toggle maximization state" shortcut, which by default is ALT+F10. (you can use the search icon to filter the list of shortcuts using keyword "F10")

Select it and use backspace to disable the shortcut. Your Alt+Shift+F10 shortcut in IntelliJ will start working again.

Edit:
On current versions of Gnome, you will find this option under *'Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > Toggle maximization state'*

Comment: this probably should be the accepted answer, did it help ya, @Will Humphreys ?

Answer (score 1):

Comment:

Michael Mills' answer is correct, but the option has moved to '*settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > Toggle maximization state*' in the current version of **Gnome**. Disabling this Shortcut re-enables IntelliJ's run shortcut

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for this useful piece of information! Please consider [suggesting an edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/463113/edit) to [Michael Mills’ answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463113/86440).

Answer (score 0):

Probably depends on what DE you're using.

In KDE, I don't think it's assigned to anything, but I've adjusted my shortcuts a bunch so I'm not entirely what the default is anymore. You can check in Settings/Shortcuts.

In Gnome, look in Settings/Devices/Keyboard to see what the existing shortcuts are.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. I probably should of mentioned that I had checked the Gnome settings already and unfortunately the shortcut is not in the list.